# Why was the Hail Mary Cloud named so?

Tags: botnet

The [Hail Mary Cloud](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/09/11/15/1653228/The-Hail-Mary-Cloud-Is-Growing?from=rss) was a botnet that slowly and intelligently attempted to bruteforce SSH logins. Why was it dubbed the *Hail Mary Cloud* though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name is just a reference to the [Hail Mary Pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_mary_pass):

> A Hail Mary pass or Hail Mary route in American football refers to any very long forward pass made in desperation with only a small chance of success, especially at or near the end of a half.

It's been used as a metaphor for anything desparate with little chance for success, which brute force attacks always are. If you read [how it works](http://bsdly.blogspot.com/2009/11/rickrolled-get-ready-for-hail-mary.html) it's sorta clever, for brute force, but each action is very low chance of working, which is why it needs a Cloud to work:

> Each attempt in theory has monumental odds against succeeding, but occasionally the guess will be right and they have scored a login.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out **the page you linked to has the answer**

> The attack is called "Hail Mary", because it should take a miracle to break in to a foreign system by "guessing passwords".

Also, it is worth noting that the third google result for "Hail Mary" is [The "Hail Mary" Pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass), which is a football term along the same lines. A second, somewhat obvious way that gives you an answer.

This may explain why your question received a down vote.

But then again, [*"Hindsight is 20-20"*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hindsight_is_20/20).

Comment: I missed the comment in my link, but I'd have never put the two together because I know zero about American football anyway!

Comment: I know the feeling. I've asked several downvoted questions myself. Only some of them last, others get deleted which is nice.

Comment: I lost a few worthless points but got two fantastic answers that satisfied my curiosity! I'll live! Thanks for your answer - shame I couldn't accept both.